# Name of this type of PHP data structure please

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

What is the name of this PHP data structure?

```php
$input = [ [750, 25], [5000, 25], [750, 75] ];
```

Thank you, Graham.

Comment: This is a multidimensional array

Comment: 2-dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

Basically array is a user-defined datatype based on the data. In the above example it's shows the two dimensional array and it is an integer data type.